# How Do I Call SQL Function inside SQL Query

Tags: orientdb

I have 2 OrientDB questions.

1. For example I have Function called getAll

   "SELECT FROM V WHERE name =:name"

I wish to retrive result in simple SQL Query 
Something liket his

```
SELECT type FROM (getAll("Test"))
```

How I can accomplish this ?

2. Is it possiable to run new SQL SELECT Query with new parameters based on previous queries?
   For Example

   SELECT $C FROM V
   LET $A = (SELECT FROM V WHERE name = 'Test1') ,
   $B = (SELECT FROM V WHERE type = 'Type1') ,
   $C = (SELECT FROM V WHERE type = $B  and name = $A)

This case is working but takes a lot of time (as i understands this happens because it runs on all content of V)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a function try this:

```
SELECT getAll("Test")
```

with this you retrieve only the RID, if you want all the properties try this:

```
SELECT expand(getAll("Test"))
```

if you want to only retrieve the type property, you can do it in 2 ways:

1. `select type from(SELECT expand(getAll("Test")))`
2. modify you function in this way `SELECT type FROM V WHERE name = :name`

For your second question you were pretty close, I've just modify it a little bit:

```
SELECT $C FROM V 
LET $A = (SELECT FROM V WHERE name = 'Test1') , 
$B = (SELECT FROM V WHERE type = 'Type1') , 
$C = (SELECT FROM V WHERE type contains $B.type and name contains $A.name)
```

Hope it helps

Regards